# Unable to use integrated graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, battery, gpu

I have a laptop with an i5 7300HQ and a GTX 1050Ti. My Nvidia GPU works fine. But if I select the Intel GPU in the Nvidia settings to save some power I am unable to login or start my laptop up.
When I installed Ubuntu I couldn't get into the OS in the conventional way without first installing Nvidia drivers (through recovery mode).
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? I really need the extra battery life.
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.3

EDIT: It's also a dual boot with windows 10

Comment: Some laptops have iGPU (Intel integrated graphics processor unit) disabled. What make and model is your laptop?

Comment: clevo n850hk1. The iGPU works fine on windows though.

Comment: clevo is a very unique platform rebranded in various countries by independent VARS. reddit might be best place for support?

Comment: It's good to try there too but I hope someone here posts an answer as well!